# Forcing git merge (I don't care about loss of commits)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've been working on an Android app with a lot of people and a obscene team managing. To simplify it we were divided in teams, each team started developing on its own repo and then, sometimes, the features were merged into the common one. I've been working on my clean branch, dedicated to my feature, and, every now and then merged with the master, just to keep in touch with what the others were doing and to avoid compatibility issues. But now I cannot merge anymore: I guess two people worked on the same feature, or something similar, and there are a lot of conflicts which I cannot resolve manually, because they are in files not used by my feature, which I didn't even care to read - they are there only to make everything works when I test my feature. More, they have to be the same as the master's, or I will have problem merging in in the future. How do I persuade git to overwrite them?

Comment: You can force git to do some things, but it will bite you back in your next merge. The best thing to do would be to stop fetching from the conflicting repositories and ask them (via email for example) to resolve their conflicts. Once the conflicting developers synchronize, you can start getting their work again.

Comment: Exactly what the professor did, I think (there were some more commits and the issues disappeared)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [git-merge man](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html). There is no 'force', but you can tell git to merge and choose your changes (instead of an automatic merge, or choosing their changes): `git merge -s recursive -X ours <branch>`